# How to make screen reader focus on an anchor tag which is inside a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have the following markup somewhere in my page:-

```html
<p>This is a paragraph which contains a <a href="https://youtube.com">link</a></p>
```

Basically a link inside a paragraph (can be multiple links).

When I navigate through the page with a screen reader (say NVDA) using the down arrow key, it focuses/highlights the paragraph and when I press the down key again, it goes to the next paragraph in the markup.

What I want it to do is to highlight and focus on the link as well and then move on to the next paragraph. I know that pressing the tab key can do that but I want the arrow keys to be able to do the same.

I noticed that wrapping the anchor tag in a `div` does what I want but it disturbs the looks since `div` is a block element and giving it `display: inline;` just makes the screen reader ignore the link again. So, is there any way to achieve what I want? Maybe a CSS solution to maintain the looks of the paragraph and change the HTML or any aria attribute which might help? I'm new to accessibility and completely clueless here.

Comment: I'm not an expert with screenreaders, but have you checked how they behave on similar webpages other than yours? If the behaviour you describe - moving to the next paragraph rather than to links etc. within the currently-selected paragraph - happens on other pages the changes are this is built-in behaviour that users of that screenreader will expect, and you shouldn't try to override it.

Answer (score 2):

Different screen readers handle navigating the DOM (*) with the downArrow key differently.

(*) really it's the accessibility tree but it's easier to think of it as the DOM

```
<p>This is a paragraph which contains a <a href="https://youtube.com">link</a> and more text after</p>
```

JAWS will behave like you're asking for and will stop at each HTML element.  So the first downArrow will navigate to the paragraph up until it hits another HTML element so will only read the paragraph text up to "contains a".  The next downArrow will read the link text.  If you had more text after the link but still within the same paragraph, JAWS would then read that, "and more text after".

- "*This is a paragraph which contains a*"
- "*Link link*'
- "*and more text after*"

NVDA handles it differently and will read an entire element including all non-block-level element children.  So it'll read the paragraph text **and** the link text **and** the text after the link that is still within the same paragraph.  That's why adding a `<div>` around your link makes NVDA stop.  Because the `<div>` is a block-level element.

- "*This is a paragraph which contains a   link    link   and more text after*"

That's just how those two screen readers behave differently.  The users of those respective screen readers know and expect this behavior.  You should not try to change this.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and explanation but in my circumstances, I must do this so is there anything that I can do here? :-(

Comment: in my circumstances, I must do this  ==> please read this answer again: you shouldn't try to interfere with that. Different screen readers work differently, period. Additionally, for your information, the behavior is customizable in screen reader options. So whatever you do, you are going against user habits and maybe will create new problems.

Comment: @AshutoshDumiyan I would love to hear **why** you must do this.  I've never seen a situation where someone has to force a screen reader to behave differently than is expected.  Is someone else telling you you need to do this based on this other person's incorrect knowledge of how screen readers work?

Comment: You still haven’t answered **why** they’re asking you to do it. My guess is they don’t understand screen readers. You should refuse to do it and point them to this conversation. They can contact me directly if they have questions.